# Pre-authentication in Spring Security + LDAP

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

Here is what I want to achieve:

I am using Websphere and I want to rely on the container to do the authentication (using Kerberos+SPNEGO).  When it come to Spring Security, I want to rely on the pre-authentication, and use LDAP to retrieve user details (roles etc) for authorization checking.

Here is the part of Spring app context config I have (tried to only include related parts)

```xml
<s:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <s:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <s:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,preAuthenticatedFilter" />
    </s:filter-chain-map>
</bean>


<s:http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" auto-config="true">
<!--
    <s:http-basic />
-->
</s:http>

<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" 
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    <property name='securityContextRepository'>
        <bean class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
            <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='true' />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="preAuthenticatedFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<s:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <s:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"   />
</s:authentication-manager>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" 
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" >
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper" >
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="ldapUserSearch"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    <property name="userDetailsMapper" >
        <bean class="com.foo.MyUserDetailsMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapContextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <!-- some setting skipped here -->
</bean>

<bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <!-- some setting skipped here -->
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <!-- some setting skipped here -->
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.simple.SimpleLdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapContextSource" />
</bean>
```

It mostly worked, I can see correct user name and role coming in for my custom `UserDetailsMapper` (com.foo.MyUserDetailsMapper) which comes from LDAP, and inside that I am returning a new `UserDetails` with updated roles.

The problem is, in my controller, when I tried to do

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

It is returning null. (For which works before I change to pre-authentication)

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem. Sorry that is mostly because of my own implementation fault which is not visible in the question itself.

My custom `UserDetails` impl is incorrectly having `getEnabled()` returning `false`. In `LdapAuthenticationProvider`, it is working fine as there is no checking on the user status.

However, in `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`, by default there is a `UserDetailsChecker` which checks the status of user, for which `getEnabled()` returning `false` will cause the user details checker to fail silently, and causing authentication not populated to `SecurityContext` (i.e. treating that account as not authenticated)

Although it is mostly my implementation issue, I think still worth leaving here as a reference for difference of `LdapAuthenticationProvider` and `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`